# A query that works in Overpass Turbo but not directly (with curl)

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have a query that works alright in Overpass Turbo, which I can't run directly by sending it with curl (it says "Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.").  As far as I can tell it's not using Overpass Turbo's extended syntax.

Here is the query that works only in Overpass Turbo:

```
area[name="Bratislava"];
way(area)[name="Štúrova"]->.my_street;
(
        nw[amenity](around.my_street:25);
        nwr[building](around.my_street:25);
        wr[highway](around.my_street:25);
);
(._;>;);
out;
```

and here is the biggest piece of it that I have been able to get working with curl --- it has only one of the original three parts of the "union" construct:

```
area[name="Bratislava"];
way[name="Štúrova"]->.my_street;
(node[amenity](around.my_street:25););
(._;>;);
out;
```

Also, I tried some other subsets of the original query, and they ran for a relatively long time and I killed them to avoid excessive server use; the whole thing runs in about 18 seconds under Overpass Turbo.

How can I get this to work under curl (eventually, I will be using it from ClojureScript in a client-side app)?

Comment: Also posted here: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/83424/why-doesnt-this-overpass-api-query-work-with-curl-although-it-works-on-overpass-turbo-and-doesnt-use

Comment: Sorry, should have linked that.  The answer is that the whitespace in the margin should be removed.

Comment: I would be easy for other to find the solution, if you can copy it here as an answer and "accept" it.